# Sorting positions in Java

Tags: java

I don't know how to put the question forth but i think an example might go a long way in clearing up the question....so here it is:

Say i have an array of strings: "Bob" "Alan" "Conrad" "Alice" "Alex".

After sorting alphabetically the array will become:"Alan" "Alex" "Alice" "Bob" "Conrad".

So we know in this case that the sorted element starting from "B" will be positioned after position number 3.

Now my question is,is there an inbuilt function in java/android which will let me know after the sorting where one group ends and the other starts (At which position the string transitions from "A" to "B")?

**EDIT**: Or maybe even two different functions used in conjunction

Comment: How could the inbuilt function know what the grouping criterion is? Suppose you had a bigger list: - aaaaa - aaaab - aaaac - aaaba - aaabc - aaabd and you'd like to know where the group starting "aaab" begins?

Comment: @mike sokolov:I only need to know where the first alphabet transitions. Like in the above i need to know when the first alphabet turns to B,not deeper in the spelling like u suggested :)

Comment: If you only need to know where the names change from "beginning with A" to "beginning with B" (after the array is sorted) then another way to look at it is you simply need to count how many names begin with "A" (even prior to sorting).

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?  binarySearch can do what you're looking for, as I mentioned below.

Comment: Binary search would solve my problem to an extent but not completely because i need the starting...binary search will throw up any random list item with that starting letter. I'm just planning to do a walk through as many suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any inbuilt function that would do this.  I doubt that there is one; partly because this seems like a relatively unusual request, and partly because it really needs a functional argument in the second step.  Guava (and other libraries) provide a `Predicate` interface that would do the trick, but there's nothing like that in the standard library.

That said, you can do this quite simply with two steps:

1. Sort the collection.  (This can't reasonably be avoided; you have to inspect every element and know their relative ordering anyway, so you can't do any better than the O(n) behaviour that sorting will impose).
2. Walk through the sorted collection, testing every element against a predicate until you find the first one that matches/doesn't match.

For the latter step if you have something like a binary tree, *and* your test lends itself to a `Comparator`-like interface, you can iterate through the tree more quickly.  But in the general case of a true/false check you can't make such assumptions, so you'd just need to walk through.  (In the fully general case with an unsorted collection you'll be performing the operation in linear time anyway so this isn't a big deal).

It would be straightforward to package this up as a library operation of your own, though (assuming that you have a definition of `Function1` or `Transformer` or similar from some library):

```
public <T> int indexOfPartition(Collection<T> coll, Function1<T, Boolean> pred, Comparator<T> cmp) {
    final Collection<T> sorted = Collections.sort(coll, cmp);
    final Iterator<T> iter = sorted.iterator();        
    int idx = 0;
    // Walk through the collection until we find an element that is "false"
    // under the predicate (i.e. not in the first partition).
    while (iter.hasNext() && pred(iter.next()) {
        idx++;
    }

    // TODO think about what you want when the collection is empty and/or when
    // the partition never changes (e.g. list of entirely strings starting
    // with "A")
    return idx;
}
```

You could dress this up with overloads to pass in default comparators and predicates, etc.

And in fact if you want the predicate to be dynamic, then instead of a `Function1<T, Boolean>` you could pass in a `Function1<T, ?>` which maps inputs to an arbitrary output object - then walk the string until the output object is different.  In your example, you could pass a function to map Strings to  their first character, depending on what you want is "when B starts" or "when the initial letter changes from the first element's".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Arrays.sort` to sort your array, but you'll have to loop yourself and find the first element starting with B to know its position.

If Guava is an option, you might use its [`Iterables.indexOf`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) method (although it would need a collection of Strings, and not an array).

Answer (score 0):

If your list is pre-sorted, look into [Collections.binarySearch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).  If you search for an item that you know would be positioned between two existing groups, such as "B", it will spit out the negative number corresponding to the list position that item would be found at.

Answer (score 0):

I think your definition of group is a bit strange... there cannot be a built in function to find such a thing because it can be defined in many different way.

I think that after sorting yo may use regular expression to find your "group transition". give a look to [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: well lets not call it a group ! lets just say i need to know where the names change from "beginning with A" to "beginning with B"

Comment: well maybe using regular expression is an overshoot... but u can match items using the string built in method string.matches("b*") and you will discover if it begins with b or not

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the data sorted in your list. Then look at how the NavigableSet#headSet or tailSet is implemented and leverage that to write your own utility functions over the sorted list.